# programmatically created View controller has black space when show or push it

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have my first `UIViewControler` which is `Home_VC`, and have it set in storyboard. When I press an article thumbnail in `Home_VC`, I am taken to `Article_VC`, the way it is called down in the code. `Article_VC` isn't set in any storyboard or nib, it is just constructed programmatically. When I call press the thumbnail, I am taken normally to the `Article_VC`, but over the tab bar and under the navigation bar, i get some black bars, I'll include a photo. Please help! And please, do not recommend using the storyboard or a nib :)

```
class Article_VC: UIViewController {

    var article : Article!

    init(with article: Article) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.article = article
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    (..............)
}

class Home_VC: UIViewController {
    func didPressThumbnail() {
        let articleVC = Article_VC(with: myArticle)
        self.navigationController?.show(articleVC, sender: self)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You made Article_VC programmatically. if yes then make it's background to white.Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Finally!! Thanks so much, it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like,

```
 class Article_VC: UIViewController {

var article : Article!

init(with article: Article) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.article = article
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


}
```

Because if you create view controller programmatically then it's view have no color, So it's take window's black color!